# Selenium WebDriver Java keyDown not working

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm learning Selenium WebDriver and have one problem. 
I want to search on amazon website for "car" with uppercaste. I use keyDown, but it does not work. The test programm fits only "car" with lowercase.

HTML code:

```
<input id="twotabsearchtextbox" value="" name="field-keywords" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" class="nav-input" dir="auto" tabindex="19" type="text">
```

JAVA code:

```
 public class FirstTestCase {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.21.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");


                WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/ref=nav_logo");

                WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox"));

                Actions builder2 = new Actions(driver);
                Action seria = builder2
                        .moveToElement(search)
                        .click()
                        .keyDown(search, Keys.SHIFT)
                        .sendKeys(search, "car")
                        .keyUp(search, Keys.SHIFT)
                        .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
                        .build();
                seria.perform();
    }
```

**Firefox version: 61.0.1**

**Geckodriver version: 0.21.0**

I would be grateful for help :)

Comment: is there any specific reason why you didn't try `search.send_keys("CAR")`?

Comment: @GPT13 yeah I'learning and want on this example learn to use Keyboard Events :)

Comment: since geckodriver, is it possible you're hitting this bug?
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/646

Comment: @SirLenz0rlot I did a few test with the HTML code there. The Shift button (down: 16) alone works, but the combination with shift + "car" did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 seria.keyDown(search, Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys("car").keyDown(search, Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();
```

This code should work properly for you.

Comment: Still "car" with lowercase

Comment: @PatrykSmandzich : When I am running your code, It is working fine at my end.

Comment: @PatrykSmandzich
    search.sendKeys(Keys.SHIFT,"car");
Can you try this

Comment: @Karthikeyan R Still the same

Comment: @PatrykSmandzich 
search.sendKeys("car".toUpperCase);
This should work, I just tried in mine and it works.

Comment: @Karthikeyan R Yes, this work. But I want to use the SHIFT button. Now for writing, then for e.g. shortcuts (like Shift+t)

Comment: For Shift+t combinations you can use Robot class
Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);

For the whole text "car" to be entered using Robot you can write
Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);

Comment: @KarthikeyanR thanks for the idea. I will use it. :)